# why only limited types allowed in switch case statements

Tags: c#, java, c++, switch-statement

Languages like `Java`,`c++`,`c`,`c#` allow `integral` type or an expression that evaluates to an integral type in switch-case statements.[`string` literals and some other types are allowed in some languages]

Why do we need to use only `integral` types or some limited number of types and not types like `double`,`float`?Is it because of some kind of **optimization** or just for **simplicity**?

Comment: This isn't the case (heh) for C# - it allows bool, char, string, integral, enum or corresponding nullable types. (So... I guess `string` is the only real standout one there.)

Comment: That's not correct. C# for example allows strings. A string is not an integral type.

Comment: Java 7 also allows strings in switch/case.

Comment: switch-case with double expression would be equivalent to just execute `default` section because of rounding errors. So why waste keyboard for typing switch/case?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: it wouldn't be equivalent -- it is *possible* for double values to compare equal, so the default would not *necessarily* be taken. But like you say, equality comparison for floating-point types can be undermined by rounding errors.

Comment: I've already seen a proposal to allow switching on strings, can't remember where.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, Java 7 allows switching on String values ... and so does C#.  (And in Java, you *can't* switch on a `long` ... thanks for reminding me Peter.)

However, the reason that switching on `float` and `double` is not allowed is most likely that the insidious effects of rounding errors and imprecise representations of floating point numbers would make code that uses floating point switches very error prone ... or require a special syntax for expressing error bounds in the `case` values.

Now if there were lots of good use-cases for switching on floating point values, then one would expect that *some* language would support this.  But to my knowledge no mainstream has programming language ever gone down this route.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of C++, it's because `switch`/`case` is not supposed to replicate the functionality of `if`. If it's supposed to provide a way to get an efficient "jump table" in cases where the code permits it.